# How do I check for membership in a C++ std::vector, etc.?

Tags: c++, stl

What am I doing wrong in the program below?

I want to use `std::find()` on a container to decide whether it contains a given element.  The program below works for an empty container, but not for one with an element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct Pair {int x,y;};

const bool operator==(Pair p, Pair q) {return p.x == p.x && q.y == q.y ;}

typedef std::vector<Pair> p_containr_t;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
  const Pair start_p = {1,2};
  const Pair second_p = {3,4};
  const Pair other_p = {5,6};
  p_containr_t v;
  p_containr_t::iterator where;

  where = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),other_p);
  assert(where == v.end());
  std::cout << "OK for empty\n";                     // Program reaches here.

  v.push_back(start_p);
  where = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),other_p);
  assert(where == v.end());                          // This assertion fails.
  std::cout << "OK for first element\n";

  v.push_back(second_p);
  where = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),other_p);
  std::cout << "OK for second element\n";      // Fails too (if I edit above).

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of deleting the question.  The answer is great.  I don't think I'd have made the mistake if we'd been pair programming.   Is the question going to help other people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is always true:

```
const bool operator==(Pair p, Pair q) {return p.x == p.x && q.y == q.y ;}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const bool operator==(Pair p, Pair q) {return p.x == p.x && q.y == q.y ;}
```

Look closely at that line.

Comment: `-Wunused` won't save you this time! :)